# What is a list assignment index out of range

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
m=[[1,0],[0,0],[0,1],[1,1],[0,1]]
e=[[0 for x in range(5)]]
for i in range (0,len(m),1):
  for j in range(0,len(m)+2,1):
    print m
    if m[0][0]==1 and m[0][1]==0:
       e[j]=2
    elif m[1][0]==0 and m[1][1]==1:
        e[j]=1
    elif m[2][0]==0 and m[2][1]==0:
         e[j]=0
    elif m[4][0]==0 and m[4][1]==1:
         e[j]=3
  print e
```

I am getting the error:

> IndexError: list assignment index out of range

I would like to keep the above loops running assigning the number to the array without experiencing the aforementioned error that I do not understand.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Showing your code properly would help, in a single line it's difficult to read.

You do e[j] = 3. You've defined e=[[0 for x in range(5)]], which means that e == [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], it's a list of 1 element, its unique element being a list of 5 element. Therefore, the only assignment you can make to e is e[0] = something. In your loop, j takes values higher than 0.

In python, if you have a list a = [1, 2] you can't do a[5] = 3, because the list is not 6-long.